# Having trouble with JS in a Zork like game - Keep getting undefined instead of intended text

Tags: javascript, function

I'm watching a tutorial on how to make a Zork like game in JavaScript and jQuery. It has been working so far but when I try to change the location running the game with a direction command, I get undefined instead of the new room.

```
var currentRoom = "start" ;

function changeRoom(dir) {
  if(rooms[currentRoom].directions[dir] !== undefined) {
    currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom].directions[dir];
    $('#game-text').append("<p>" + rooms[currentRoom].description + "</p>");
  } else {
      $('#game-text').append("<p> You cannot go that way </p>");
  }
}
```

EDIT: This code comes after the code above

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#game-text').append("<p>" + rooms.start.description + "</p>");

    $(document).keypress(function(key){
      if(key.which === 13 && $('#user-input').is(':focus')){
          var value = $('#user-input').val().toLowerCase();
          switch(value) {
            case "north":
              changeRoom("north");
              break;
            case "south":
              changeRoom("south");
              break;
              case "east":
              changeRoom("east");
              break;
              case "west":
              changeRoom("west");
              break;
            default:
              alert("Invalid move!")
          }
      }
    })

})
```

I think it has something to do with this portion of code. The message "you can not go that way" appears when it should; but I do not get the description of the room that I entered - only a message of undefined. Sorry if I'm being unclear, this is my fist attempt at making a game and I know  very little about JavaScript.

EDIT: These are two of the "rooms".

```
var rooms = {
  "start": {
    "description": "It is a sunny day, perfect for a walk!\
    While walking, you come across an intersection;\
    you can go <b>North</b>, <b>South</b>, <b>East</b> or\
    <b>West</b>, which way do you choose?",
  "directions": {
    "north": "deadend",
    "west": "shortcut",
    "east": "garden",
    "south": "home"
    }
  "garden": { 
    "discription": "Ahh the right path, I see you choose the long\
  way around which leads through a lovley garden",
    "directions": {
      "west": "start",
      "east": "deadend"
    }
  },
```

Comment: We need to see more code in order to help. Can you include what `rooms` is set to, and what `dir` is set to?

Comment: is it the type conditional not equals !== ?
Have you tried the traditional not equal != ?

Comment: What does the debugger say the value of `room[currentRoom].description` is? Maybe it really is undefined.

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: I added more info. The debugger is saying nothing is wrong. The code is "working" just not as intended. When i choose to go east it says undefined. If keep going east it says i I can not go that way. So I'm assuming that it recognizes that I'm changing rooms

Comment: Is the `rooms` declaration above your `$(document).ready(function(){` line?

Comment: @JasperBirkeneder Let's be perfectly clear.  `The debugger is saying nothing is wrong`  This isn't something the debugger says.  Have you set a breakpoint on the offending line to inspect the variables on that line?  Which variables do not have the expected values?

Comment: @Amy The JS for the rooms and the functions are on different pages but linked to an html.

Comment: @JasperBirkeneder I don't see how that is relevant.  You can still set breakpoints in those files.

Comment: Do you know when you get `undefined` when accessing a property? When the property does not exist.You have a typo: `discription` instead of `description` in `garden`. So `description` doesn't exist.